# Allow IIS Authorization to Javascript files in secured location

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, security, webforms

I am working in an ASP.net Webforms application.  I have a folder that is secured by web.config authorization that runs a particular webform.  That webform references an external Javascript file.  Currently that folder is in a public location (i.e. /Content/Scripts), and all works fine.

I would like to be able to move this file to the secured location so that only the approved roles would be able to access it.

The problem that I encounter is that when I move it to the secure folder, and adjust the reference accordingly, the .js doesn't get referenced properly.

My authorization for the secure folder looks like this:

```
<authorization>
      <allow roles="secure_role1, secure_role2"/>      
      <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

While I am currently logged in as one of the approved roles (i.e. "secure_role1"), my application will still not be able to access the .js file unless I remove the "deny users" clause.  I can't do this because it opens up that secure location for users from other roles to crawl.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do the following:

- Added the Security / URL Authorisation role to your server or feature in IIS. See: 
  https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authorization
- Enable windows authentication and disabled anon auth?
- Put in the correct <location> tag around your authorisation tag? Like so:

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="secure_role1"/> 
        <deny users="*"/> 
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

- Are you sure that Roles are working? Maybe try adding your specific user account first and see if that works.

BTW typically I wouldn't bother protecting JS files. They shouldn't contain any security specific code. You should be more worried about protecting your server-side code from users without the correct roles.